# Dynamic variable always linked to a method in Python

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global-variables

I create a tkinter root :

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

and would like to create a *dynamic* variable which would be always linked to some property (or is it called a method?) of `root` :

```
X = root.winfo_width()
```

If `root`'s `winfo_width()` changes, I would like that `X` is automatically updated.

How to do this?
 Is it called an alias ? a dynamic variable ?

Comment: That isn't possible with a plain variable.  However, if you have an object `obj`, you can make it so that `obj.x` accesses `root.winfo_width()` under the hood, so it always returns the "synced" value.

Comment: Ok. How to design such an object?

Comment: Or another solution : is there a way of creating an **alias** : X is just a shortcut interpreted as `root.winfo_width()` ?

Comment: What do you want to use `X` for?

Comment: just read `X` a lot of times everywhere in my code (not write `X`, just read it)

Comment: What you probably should do is include an update method that is called, say, once every 200ms, and changes the value of `X` to the current `root.winfo_width()`. Attempting to force a function into a variable is just an awkward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a shorthand,

```
X = root.winfo_width

print X()
```

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to have `X` (and not `X()`) as a shorthand for `root.winfo_width`?

Comment: No. `X` is a value. `X()` is a function. You want to call a function (`root.winfo_width`); therefore, you must use a function to do so.

Comment: Even if you *could* write `X`, it would make your code totally unreadable if `X` (a value) is suddenly and non-obviously changing.

Comment: yes, you're right : it is more readable to see that `X` is a function

Comment: And if I want `X()` to be a shortcut for `float(root.winfo_width)`, is it possible as well ? I have to deal with `float` because I want things like `2 / X()` to be a `float` and not an `int` (it would be zero all the time!)

Comment: I'm not talking about the lambdas, but this "X = root.winfo_width()" does not update the value of X if root.winfo_width changes

Comment: Are you sure @Liarez ?

Comment: I tried in python console, you can check it. Am I wrong ? If you make "X = root.winfo_width()"  X gets the value of root.winfo_width(), but after 10 secs root.winfo_width() changes its value, X does not update itself

Comment: @PaulDraper This lambda trick still returns a function; what is the difference wrt. your published answer?

Comment: @Liarez: You typed the wrong thing in your console. Try again without the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need exactly, `@property` decorator may do the trick (based on @BrenBarn's answer):

```
class X(object):
    @property  # <-- this 'decorator' provides the necessary magic
    def x(self):
        return time.time()  # <-- just for example of refresh
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.x)
```

Now we can do:

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x
1386929249.63
>>> x
1386929250.27
```

But that may be a trick linked to the interpreter, but you still can do the following:

```
>>> x.x
1386929251.14
>>> x.x
1386929253.01
```

If you have several such "dynamic properties", you can just group them in one class, and access them this way (but this may not be a good idea, in terms of readability, to hide dynamic behavior of a property).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, although Python is really dynamic, there are a few things that always do exactly the same thing that can't be changed.

One is simple assignment:

```
x = ...some complex expression...
```

This always does the same thing: it evaluates "some complex expression", and then x is changed so that it is now a reference to the result of the expression.

The other is variable evaluation:

```
x
```

Simply using a single variable never invokes any code or methods or anything -- in the expression where you use x, x is simply "replaced" by whatever it is referring to.

So doing exactly what you want isn't possible, there's no place to add something dynamic. Method lookup is an obvious alternative:

```
x.y
```

Here, you could implement x.**getattr** to return the thing you need (too tricky), or you could give x a property method y (as in the other answers).

The other thing is that x could refer to a *mutable* object, and it could be x's *contents* that change. E.g., if x refers to a dictionary,

```
x = root.winfo_dimensions()
print x['width']
```

Then you could make it so that `root` keeps an instance of that dictionary itself, and updates it when the width changes. Maybe it only keeps one and returns that. But then you can also *change* the contents from elsewhere, and that's tricky.

I wouldn't do any of this at all and just call root.winfo_width() where needed. Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you how to make an "alias" of the function, i hope it helps you.

```
def X():
    return root.winfo_width()
```

You make that definition, so each time you call "X()" you get the value of root.winfo_width(). If the value of root.winfo_wifth() changes, and you call X(), you get the updated value